# How to catch oledbdatareader errors

Tags: vb.net

I have this code i wrote to find out if a record exists in data base. It works well when record is found. If it isn't, it brings up an error. I would like the error to be caught in a messagebox that states "record not found" instead.

```
         Dim findprinc As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 16)
        MsgBox(findprinc)
        sql = "Select RealID from Dets where ID like '%" & findprinc &                "%'"
        MsgBox(sql)
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\new.mdb")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim numeri As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        numeri.Read()
```

Comment: before you `.Read` check if `numeri.HasRows`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim findprinc As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 16)
    MsgBox(findprinc)
    Sql = "Select RealID from Dets where ID like '%" & findprinc & "%'"
    MsgBox(Sql)
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\new.mdb")
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)
    Dim numeri As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim recordFound As Boolean = False
    While numeri.Read
        recordFound = True
    End While
    If recordFound = False Then
        MsgBox("Record Not Found")
    End If
```